# How to map based on multiple lists with arbitrary elements?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have the following model:

```
case class Car(brand: String, year: Int, model: String, ownerId: String)
case class Person(firstName: String, lastName: String, id: String)
case class House(address: String, size: Int, ownerId: String)
case class Info(id: String, lastName: String, carModel: String, address: String)
```

I want to build a `List[Info]` based on the following lists:

```
val personL: List[Person] = List(Person("John", "Doe", "1"), Person("Jane", "Doe", "2"))
val carL: List[Car] = List(Car("Mercedes", 1999, "G", "1"), Car("Tesla", 2016, "S", "4"), Car("VW", 2015, "Golf", "2"))
val houseL: List[House] = List(House("Str. 1", 1000, "2"), House("Bvl. 3", 150, "8"))
```

The info should be gathered based on the `personL`, for example:

```
val info = personL.map { p =>
      val car = carL.find(_.ownerId.equals(p.id))
      val house = houseL.find(_.ownerId.equals(p.id))
      val carModel = car.map(_.model)
      val address = house.map(_.address)
      Info(p.id, p.lastName, carModel.getOrElse(""), address.getOrElse(""))
      }
```

Result:

```
info: List[Info] = List(Info(1,Doe,G,), Info(2,Doe,Golf,Str. 1))
```

Now I am wondering if there's an expression which is more concise than my map construct which solves exactly my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option by building the maps from ownerid to model and address firstly, and then look up the info while looping through the person List:

```
val carMap = carL.map(car => car.ownerId -> car.model).toMap
// carMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(1 -> G, 4 -> S, 2 -> Golf)

val addrMap = houseL.map(house => house.ownerId -> house.address).toMap
// addrMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(2 -> Str. 1, 8 -> Bvl. 3)

personL.map(p => Info(p.id, p.lastName, carMap.getOrElse(p.id, ""), addrMap.getOrElse(p.id, "")))
// res3: List[Info] = List(Info(1,Doe,G,), Info(2,Doe,Golf,Str. 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say use for comprehensions. If you need exactly that result which in that case would resemble a [left join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp) then the for comprehension is still ugly:

```scala
for {
  person  <- persons
  model   <- cars.find(_.ownerId == person.id).map(_.model).orElse(Some("")).toList
  address <- houses.find(_.ownerId == person.id).map(_.address).orElse(Some("")).toList
} yield Info(person.id, person.lastName, model, address)
```

Note that you can remove the `.toList` call in this exceptional case as the two Option generators appear after the collection generators.

If you can sacrifice the default model / address values then it looks simple enough:

```scala
for {
  person <- persons
  car    <- cars if car.ownerId == person.id
  house  <- houses if house.ownerId == person.id
} yield Info(person.id, person.lastName, car.model, car.address)
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

May be converting the individual lists in hashmaps with a map function and look up by key instead of iterating all those lists for every element of person might help?